# which thread is blocked waiting for the thread join() to complete in this short example for SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, graphics, surfaceview

can someone explain what what is going on here for which thread is being blocked?  the thread object here is used for canvas and drawing graphics, the join() method is called on this graphics thread so it will continue to finish.  while the other thread is blocked and waiting.  which thread is this?

if the surfaceView class is running on the main UI thread than the UI will be blocked waiting for the graphics thread to finish.  this does not make sense.  so the other explanation would be for there to be three separate threads here. the main UI thread, the graphics thread where join() is being called on, and a third thread for surface view that is getting blocked while the graphics thread finishes

is there in fact three threads running, and the UI thread is not the one being blocked?

nowhere in my code did I start a new thread for SurfaceView.  I only instantiated a SurfaceView object.

as this code is written it looks like the main UI thread is blocked waiting for the graphics thread to finish.

If the SurfaceView object is instantiated inside of a thread or AsyncTask then it would look more clear.

// this code is located inside of the SurfaceView class

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // can also put this code in surfaceChanged
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(surfaceRunnable);
    thread.start();

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    running = false;
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
        thread.join();
        retry = false;
        } catch( InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: The thread that executes the `thread.join()` is the one being blocked, not the thread represented by `thread`.

Comment: does that mean surfaceDestoryed is called by a background thread and not the main UI thread?

Comment: If you add log messages to some of the code (`surfaceCreated()`, `surfaceDestroyed()`, `surfaceRunnable.run()`, then view the logcat output with `adb logcat -v threadtime`, you can see the thread IDs next to the log messages.  That makes it easy to map activity to specific threads.  What would be even better is to attach a debugger and just look and see what all the threads are and where each thread has stopped -- then you will know not only what, but why.

Comment: thank you for the comments, I am doing that right now to see which thread is where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread that is blocked is the **UI thread**. Proving this with a debugger is a good idea. You can confirm this by viewing the source code of `SurfaceView.java` (if in Eclipse, hit `F3` while the cursor is on the text `SurfaceView`). In particular:

The callbacks such as `surfaceDestroyed()` are called from `SurfaceView.updateWindow()`:

```
private void updateWindow(boolean force, boolean redrawNeeded) {
    ...
    callbacks = getSurfaceCallbacks();
    for (SurfaceHolder.Callback c : callbacks) {
        c.surfaceDestroyed(mSurfaceHolder);
    }
```

`updateWindow()` is called from the anonymous class derived from `Handler` and assigned to `mHandler`:

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case KEEP_SCREEN_ON_MSG: {
                setKeepScreenOn(msg.arg1 != 0);
            } break;
            case GET_NEW_SURFACE_MSG: {
                handleGetNewSurface();
            } break;
            case UPDATE_WINDOW_MSG: {
                updateWindow(false, false);
            } break;
        }
    }
};
```

Note that this `mHandler` object is constructed when the `SurfaceView` object is constructed, which happens on the UI thread. And note that the `Handler` constructor binds the `Handler` to the `Looper` associated with the current thread (the UI thread). So `handleMesssage()` runs on that `Looper` which is the UI thread's `Looper`. Thus, `updateWindow()` is called on the UI thread.

`updateWindow()` is also called several other times in the file and most of the time it is easy to deduce that it is being called from the UI thread.